# Is it possible to locate a smartphone through its SIM number in use programmatically through PHP?

Tags: php, geolocation

I have to develop a web-based  system (HTML, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP) which will send an SMS to the nearby donors whose information is already there in the database (near to hospital where blood is needed) in case of blood request from a hospital.

In that context I would like to know if a device can be located using the SIM number in use through PHP. If no, what other alternative/mechanism can be used for locating a device from a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A web browser on a smartphone, like its desktop counterpart, only has limited access to the device on which is runs. It would be an enormous privacy and legal nightmare to give websites unrestricted access to device-level hardware identifiers.

Some people have tried to implement "[undeletable cookies](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=undeletable+cookies)" (and such enterprises are widely considered highly unethical, if not necessarily illegal in all jurisdictions). However, even they do not tie a device to a personal identity, or indeed to a ever-changing location.

If you want to track a user's location using GPS, then:

(a) write an Android/iOS app to do that in the background, or see if there is an existing OS-level service or app to do that for you,
(b) and ensure the user gives permission for that data to flow from their device on a regular basis,
(c) and allow the user to opt-out of this tracking at any time.

You will need to consider your users' battery consumptions here, too, since usage of the GPS subsystem tends to be power-hungry.

Alternatively you could look at [browser geolocation](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) and send this information back periodically to your server, though note that this does not necessarily use GPS (and so can be inaccurate) and it only runs when your website is open and the browser is open. While this approach is quick to implement, it thus is not a very reliable way of getting geolocation information on a long-term basis.